# Storing nested JSON on the server

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have (mock) product data hard coded into a JSON file that I use to generate "catalogue" pages in my application. However, the ultimate plan is to allow users to add new products via a CMS style admin panel.

Obviously I need this data to be persistent. The obvious choice would be to use MySQL or some other database, but since this a a pretty complex data structure with lots of nesting I can't imagine how that could be achieved painlessly. I could simply store the JSON in a text file on the server but then I lose the ability to manipulate it and have to send the whole set each time I make a change. Then again that would only be when people added and removed  products so perhaps it wouldn't be so bad. Perhaps I could decode the JSON with PHP, manipulated it and then re-serialize it into JSON and save it into a text file.

Sorry, I'm rambling here. What do you think are my best options?

```
{
        currency: currency,
        currencySymbol: CurrencySymbol(currency),
        shoes: {
            title: 'Shoes',
            items:[ 
                [
                    {
                        name: 'Light Shoes', 
                        price: 99.99, 
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/shoes/darkshoes.jpg'
                    },{
                        name: 'Dark Shoes', 
                        price: 59.99, 
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/shoes/darkshoes.jpg'
                    },{
                        name: 'Brown Shoes',
                        price: 5.99,
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/shoes/darkshoes.jpg'
                    }
                ],[
                    {
                        name: 'Gold Shoes',
                        price: 999.99,
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/shoes/darkshoes.jpg'
                    },{
                        name: 'Dark Shoes', 
                        price: 59.99, 
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/shoes/darkshoes.jpg'
                    },{
                        name: 'Brown Shoes',
                        price: 5.99,
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/shoes/darkshoes.jpg'
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        dance: {
            title: 'Dance Gear',
            items: [ 
                [
                    {
                        name: 'Cool Cap', 
                        price: 99.99, 
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/dance/dance.jpg'
                    },{
                        name: 'Baggy Pants', 
                        price: 59.99, 
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/dance/dance.jpg'
                    },{
                        name: 'Jacket',
                        price: 5.99,
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/dance/dance.jpg'
                    }
                ],[
                    {
                        name: 'T-Shirt',
                        price: 99.99,
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/dance/dance.jpg'
                    },{
                        name: 'Hip-Hip Hoodie', 
                        price: 59.99, 
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/dance/dance.jpg'
                    },{
                        name: 'Belt',
                        price: 5.99,
                        description: "Donec eu lacus vel sapien luctus fermentum. Nulla consequat viverra volutpat. Phasellus et sagittis mauris.", 
                        imgUrl:'./catalogue/dance/dance.jpg'
                    }
                ]
            ]

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use MongoDB :), it's much better for this!

Comment: I'l take a look at that, thanks

Comment: You can also check this out: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/webdev-with-mongodb-part1/

Answer (score 2):

Store json objects with a **.json** extension. No need for a text file here, and therefore no need to keep struggling with sending the correct headers.

For the persistence part: In your database table only reference the json files on the local file system along with other information you need (time it was updated etc.).

A sample table could look like this:

`documents(id:pk, file, created_at, updated_at)`

*(Of course you could also store the raw json string in your table but you would run into danger using a data-type that is not suited to store the json and therefore cannot hold all of the data)*

However this approach would only be suitable when you **need to use relational database systems**

---

However, a better approach would be to use document database systems such as [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) which also has been recommended in the comments. It's definitely worth a look, but it can be a bit awkward at first if you are coming from a relational dbms background.